# Classification of std::vector's iterators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

In the description of `std::vector` on cppreference (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin), I miss the categorization of the iterator (according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) that is returned by the `begin()` function (the same applies for the iterator returned by `end()`).

Does cppreference not have to state which category of iterator is returned by `begin()` so that the user knows the iterator's functionality?
Currently, for me, it remains unclear which functionality `std::vector`'s iterators provide.

Comment: Try looking at the main `std::vector` page on cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Here you can see that under `Iterator` it gives a link to `RandomAccessIterator` which specifies the properties of `std::vector<T>`'s iterators.

Comment: There's a new category of contiguous iterator being introduced in c++17, which also applied to vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the main desciption of `std::vector` under the section [Member types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types):

> ```
> iterator               RandomAccessIterator
> const_iterator         Constant random access iterator
> reverse_iterator       std::reverse_iterator<iterator>
> const_reverse_iterator std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>
> ```

`std::vector` uses [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)

> A RandomAccessIterator is a BidirectionalIterator that can be moved to
>   point to any element in constant time. A pointer to an element of an
>   array satisfies all requirements of RandomAccessIterator
>   ...

Answer (score 2):

On the [cppreference page for `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) you will find:

```
Member types
============

  ...

iterator    RandomAccessIterator
```

Answer (score 2):

From here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector you can see that a vector's iterators model the `RandomAccessIterator` concept: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator

`std::vector::begin()` returns a `std::vector::iterator` (or `const_iterator`)

`std::begin(x)` returns the result of `x.begin()`

Therefore std::begin(std::vector<...>) will return a random access iterator.